# Remove caret from HTML text input

Tags: html, css, forms, text

I'm trying to create a hidden textfield for an iphone specific site, basically I've taken a textfield, hidden all of its elements and show an image instead, when clicked this pops up an onscreen keyboard, as well as submitting when the form loses focus.

What I can't get rid of is the text caret. It flashes at me as if I'm some loser who can't set his VCR to anything but 12:00.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just change the type of the input element to "hidden" when it's not supposed to be edited? E.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="datafield" id="datafield" />
```

That way it won't allow for the caret to be standing on it. If you need its value to be displayed, add a `DIV` and populate it with the *datafield* value. Then just put a click event on the `DIV` to activate the input field.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried disabling the text field as well? `disabled="disabled"`

Comment: This makes the whole textfield unclickable now.

Im using opacity:0; on the Textfield, with the image I want to show being the background for the containing div underneath.

If I could change the color of the I-bar that would be fantastic as well... just need it out of my life.